# What does "dest_directory = FLAGS.model_dir" mean?

Tags: python, tensorflow, command-line, deep-learning, image-recognition

I am trying to understand TenserFlow image classification. Got following [code](https://github.com/shivakrishna9/tensorflow-retrain) from GitHub, starts from 298 line in "retrain.py" script.

```
dest_directory = FLAGS.model_dir
if not os.path.exists(dest_directory):
os.makedirs(dest_directory)
```

What does `"FLAGS.model_dir"` mean and where is this directory located?

Answer (score 2):

`FLAGS` holds parsed command line arguments. This script uses [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) library, but the style is inherited from [gflags](/questions/tagged/gflags) library, originally developed internally at Google in C++, then open sources and ported to different languages.

What `FLAGS.model_dir` means is easy to see from the parser definitions:

```
parser.add_argument(
      '--model_dir',
      type=str,
      default='/tmp/imagenet',
      help="""\
      Path to classify_image_graph_def.pb,
      imagenet_synset_to_human_label_map.txt, and
      imagenet_2012_challenge_label_map_proto.pbtxt.\
      """
  )
```

So, its location is specified by the user when she runs the script. If nothing it specified, this path is used: `'/tmp/imagenet'`.

Comment: Script doesn't ask any directory where to put downloaded data set. It just start downloading. Problem is that I had interrupted the download now script try to access that downloaded file that is missing or not completely downloaded, causing run time error and script now doesn't run. `/tmp/imagenet` where is this directory, So I can delete it and data can be re-downloaded.

Comment: If I want to manually code different directory path, how it can be done?

Comment: Right, it doesn't ask. It relies on the right arguments. If you run `train.sh`, it uses `--model_dir=inception`, so the model is in the nearby `inception` dir